# MS Access New record in form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am making a data entry MS Access based database. It has a main screen, where I enter the person ID, and once I click `Create`, it directs to a navigation form which displays 4 other forms (basically 4 pages of data entries for 1 person).

This form also displays the person_ID and date in the header. When I enter the person ID and click `Create`, I should be able to enter the details for that respective record.  But when the form opens it redirects to the first record in the DB and not that particular record. Kindly suggest me the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To open a form on a particular record you can use DoCmd.OpenForm method with a WhereCondition.

On the first form have a text box for the person_ID.
This will be referred to as me!person_ID in your code.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2", acNormal, , "person_ID = " & me!person_ID
```

That's it.

For something a little more advanced you can use the forms Form.OpenArgs property.
The code below does not allow the form to be opened unless an OpenArgs is supplied.
That may not be necessary but It prevents users from opening the form through a route I do not wish them to take.

Then the code behind the "Create" button will be something like:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form2",  acNormal, , , , acNormal, me!person_ID
```

On the form you wish to open on the specific record on ( Form2 ) use the following code in the "On Open" event:

```
Private Sub Form2_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    If IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        MsgBox "Open from the first form, I won't work otherwise"
        DoCmd.Close , "Form2"
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Me.Filter = "person_ID = """ & Me.OpenArgs & """"

    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

The filter is now set in the second form's "On Open" event rather than being supplied by the WhereCondition on the first forms Create buttons "On Click" event.

As a design choice have you thought about using a single form and having a "Tab Control" with a tab in place of each of your forms. Instead of the Create button opening the next form it simply changes tab.

This is my first post on stackoverflow, did I do good?

Comment: Hey, you did amazing! I am happy to get a response so quickly. Well, I need some more support from you. 
I figured out that my database can have same person_ID for different records, its not the primary key anyway. So instead of redirecting the form to the specific person_ID, I want the form to open the last record added, since that will be the new ID which I add from the first page and have to add data to that specific record.

Comment: Currently the form loads the first entry of the database. 

I added the following in the Create button:
>DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
>DoCmd.OpenForm "Fund_ValMain"

and 
>DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast
 as a onload event for the form. But it doesnt load the last record always. 

If you want we can have a private conversation regarding the issue and I can share screenshots of the product. I really need your guidance in figuring this out.

Comment: Hi Shoumik Goswami, I think it will be unreliable, as you have found out, to go to the last record, the order may be changed by a user for instance. This can be changed on the "On Open" event of course. If the last record should always be the record you want then try requerying and refreshing the form too. I suggest using a unique field if possible, then you know for a fact that the correct record will open on the form. Also, ensure the forms that are to be opened are closed before re-opening, if its not then the form may display the previous record that was opened.

Comment: I have an unique field, the ID which generates auto numbers and is also the primary key. But the user wont be entering this ID, he will only enter the person_ID. So is it possible to use the autonumber ID someway to open the last record or the desired record?

Answer (score 0):

in form properties simply go to Data tab and set Data entry to "No"